# Hibernate Search and external Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a question about hibernate search. I have researched but could not found any answer yet. The simple scenerio;
I have a Foo entity in my project.

```
class Foo{
Bar bar;
}
```

This entity can not be annotated with Indexable since it is an external class which comes from jar.
I am able to perform CRUD operations via FooQueryApi . I have Foo records in database. Is it possible somehow integrate this Foo entity and hibernate-search  ? If so let me know how could I do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new class in your project that extends original class and annotate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [programmatic API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi) for defining index mappings.

Check out the reference guide for the complete description, it'd look roughly like this:

```
SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();

mapping.entity(Foo.class)
    .indexed()
    .property( "bar", ElementType.METHOD )
        .indexEmbedded();
```

Don't forget to add the mapping to the configuration when bootstrapping Hibernate ORM as shown in the reference documentation.